# Map : Reverse geocoding request : Jquery async request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary

I have implemented reverse geocoding in the map. We are sending around 1000 reverse geocoding  async request at a time to the map server and at that time my browser got hangs for 6-7 seconds. I am using JQUERY for it and it's async request than why browser gets hang. May i know the reason behind it  and alternative solution for it?

Note : I am using MVC 3.

Answer (score 1):

Sending 1000 AJAX requests to your server seems like a huge load for the browser to handle. What if you have 2 users browsing your site at the same time? What if you have 3? What if you have 100? Your web server won't last for long.

I would recommend you rethinking your design so that you send fewer AJAX requests but with larger payload data, i.e. aggregate multiple requests into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried combining all the requests into one request? this will speed the page load as you will be making a minimum of 1001 requests